# Installing entity framework in visual studio 2015 missing supported tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-4

I am trying to install entity framework 4 beta for vs2015. Firstly I downloaded EFPowerTools at visualstudiogallery then I changed to name(.zip) and then I opened extension.vsixmanifest with notepad. But at every video different from mine. In my extension.vsixmanifest hasn't got  tags. So I cant add visual studio community 15.0 etc. What can I do?

Comment: download entity framework from Nuget Package Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use "EF 6 Power Tools Community Edition" - works with VS 2017 and VS 2017 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition